# Am I someone else's vector?

Tags: attack-vector

I have a site that is open to the public, that exposes no resources that need authorization.  I have a use case that should support return URLs.  In some cases, the site will redirect the session to a return URL after interaction with my site.

The return URL poses no risk to any of my resources.  The session can browse around a bit and then leave.  I could see, though, that somebody could construct a request with a return URL, POST it to my site, have it redirect to that URL.  Even though I am not harmed, what have I exposed?

Comment: A semi-popular website did that a year or two ago, allowing people to abuse their site to redirect to arbitrary domains. The stubborn admin did not consider it an issue until I started using it for my own purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've exposed the reputation of your site. If your site is used as part of a phishing or other attack where you redirect users, your domain may be blacklisted.

This may prevent you from sending or receiving email on that domain.

Your domain may be blocked by corporate filters if it's linked to malicious activity.

Google might mark your site as malicious and warn users.

There are indirect costs associated with being used in malicious activity, and while it may not directly be your fault you still may pay the price.